# What do I do if Texlive installation does not complete? Do I have to delete the installed files and start from scratch?

Tags: installing

I have a slow (sat.) connection.  The installation ran for over half an hour and then stopped around item 234: TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install babel-azerbaijani
babel-azerbaijani will be retried later.
Installing [0233/4479, time/total: 56:37/12:35:59]: babel-basque [161k]
The system cannot find the path specified.
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (download_file failed) for https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/babel-basque.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install babel-basque
babel-basque will be retried later.
Installing [0234/4479, time/total: 56:44/12:37:32]: babel-belarusian [176k]
Error in tempdir() using

Is there a way to try the installation again without having to delete what was downloaded so far?  If I don't delete the installation I get a message warning me that the directory already contains files and this could cause problems.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: it is probably better to download first and to install in a second step. See https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-mirror.html

Comment: Alternatively, rather than getting a full mirror, you can try installing a 'minimal' install, and adding packages individually afterwards (from the error above: do you really need Azerbaijani *and* Basque *and* Belarusian?). On at least one install I did, the default install was some (single digit) amount of gigabytes, the minimal was a small number of hundred megabytes (it's been a while, and the numbers may be wrong). This was on a relatively slow internet connection as well. Time difference: about 4 hours (didn't finish, for unrelated reasons) vs about 30 minutes.